# How to get UgcPostURN

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to fetch video data from LinkedIn Page. I need to know UgcPost URN. However, I cant find one. Where can I get the URN.

I tried to use organization urn in stead of UgcPost Urn. However, it is not working at all.

Comment: what programing language you are using ?

Comment: I am using C# and postman !